# Ant: delete using several name paterns in a loop

Tags: loops, ant, ant-contrib

Out of directory "`res`" I want to delete all files with names appearing in directories `"platforms/${patern.dir}/res"`, where `pattern.dir` is a member of comma-separated list specified by parameter `pattern.dirs`   I want to organize that as a loop, so that the number of directories for name patterns can be changed without target modification.

Here is the task that is supposed to do that:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>

<target name="-clean-irrelevant" if="pattern.dirs" >
    <for list="${pattern.dirs}" param="pattern.dir">
         <delete verbose="true">
            <fileset dir="res" includes="**/*" >
                <present present="srconly"
                 targetdir="platforms/${pattern.dir}/res"/>     
            </fileset>  
        </delete>    
    </for>
</target>
```

When I run the task, I get the message

```
The following error occurred while executing this line:
for doesn't support the nested "delete" element.
```

Tried foreach, also antcall of a stand-alone delete task - no luck.

Is there a way to implement the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place a `sequential` element after the `for` loop, which should contain the tasks to be run for each iteration.

To access the list parameter `pattern.dir`, you need to use `@{}` instead of `${}`.

```
<target name="-clean-irrelevant" if="pattern.dirs" >
    <for list="${pattern.dirs}" param="pattern.dir">
        <sequential>
            <delete verbose="true">
                <fileset dir="res" includes="**/*" >
                    <present present="srconly"
                       targetdir="platforms/@{pattern.dir}/res"/>     
                </fileset>  
            </delete> 
        </sequential>           
    </for>
</target>
```

Comment: I changed $ by @, but it didn't help: the message stayed the same. Also I tried with ant-contrib 1.03 (beta) instead of ant-contrib 0.6. This gives me a different message: "Invalid type class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Delete used in For task, it does not have a public iterator method", which is in effect probably the same.

Comment: @cyanide Did you add the `sequential` element as mentioned in the answer? Could you post the updated target code?

Comment: Adding <sequential> really helped. Thank you